# Using Apotomo gem to build a user-driven widget page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget, cells, apotomo

I am trying to use `apotomo` for setting up widgets in my app and have been running into a few issues.  I've tried researching, but haven't found anything useful yet.  Hopefully, someone might have some experience here.

Here is my setup:

- I have Users model (set up via Devise), who can each create custom pages (Pages model).
- Each Page can have a number of widgets.  The `PagesController#show` view is used to display a published version of the page or preview the page for the user.  The `PagesController#edit` view is used to display the page in "edit" mode w/ forms for each widget, allowing the user to update them as needed.
- I have a Widgets model with a serialized "data" field that holds the values for each widget.  (Things such as `title`, `url`, etc).

The issue I am running into is displaying each user's customized widget.

For the sake of this question, let's assume I have a single widget "PicturesWidget".  I've added the widget to the `PagesController` like so:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  has_widgets do |root|
    root << widget(:pictures)
  end
  ...
end
```

I have two views in the Pages controller: "PagesController#Edit" and "PagesController#Show".  I also defined two views in the widget controller, one is "PicturesWidget#edit" and the default is "PicturesWidget#display".  From the edit and show views, I use something like this to load the widgets:

```
# In views/pages/show.html.erb:
<%= render_widget :pictures, :display, ... %>
# In views/pages/edit.html.erb:
<%= render_widget :pictures, :edit, ... %>
```

However, the main issue I am running into is the fact that the user can have multiple widgets per page.  In other words, I have to pass in the serialized `data` field into each widget, so it can display the content in `PicturesWidget#display` or `PicturesWidget#edit` views.  In the `PagesController` I do:

```
def show
  @user = ...
  @page = @user.pages.find(params[:page_id])
  @widgets = @page.widgets
end
```

And in `views/pages/show.html.erb` I use the following loop:

```
<% @widgets.each do |widget| %>
  <%= render_widget :pictures, :display, :widget => widget %>
<% end %>
```

This ends up passing-in each individual widget ActiveRecord as an argument to the `PicturesWidget` controller.  In the widget controller, I added "args" to both `display` and `edit` methods:

```
def display(args)
  @widget = args[:widget]
  @title = @widget.data[:title]
  @url = @widget.data[:url]
  render
end
```

This is causing me issues all over the place because when I have to re-render the view or replace it with another, I usually get complaints that "args" is not present, and I have no way to pass it in.

In Apotomo documentation I found that we are supposed to use options instead of args in the newer version of the gem.  Options are pulled from  the "has_widget" method in the original `PagesController`:

```
has_widgets do |root|
  root << widget(:pictures, :data => @data)
end
```

In this case `options[:data]` would return `@data`.  However, I need to provide data per each widget, not a global `@data` var.  I wasn't able to find any examples of how others are doing this.  Any suggestions?  Or should I just scrap the whole thing and write my own Widget Controller?  Or downgrade to cells and write my own AJAX handlers?

Sorry for the long write-up.  I reckon someone else might run into this issue and hopefully this helps them out.

Thanks,
Nick

---

[Edit] As suggested, I ended up adding unique widgets as so:

```
@page.widgets.each do |indiv_wid|
  root << widget(indiv_wid.kind.to_sym, indiv_wid.id, data: indiv_wid.data)
end
```

Had to override one of the modules to allow use of apotomo_root in the controller/views:

```
module Apotomo
  module Rails    
    module ActionViewMethods
      delegate :render_widget, :apotomo_root, :url_for_event, :to => :controller
    end
  end
end
```

(Added `:apotomo_root` above)

Used this in the controller to get a list of all the loaded widgets:

```
apotomo_root.each do |x|            
  @widget_ids << x.widget_id unless x.widget_id == :root
end
```

And then I simply iterated over it in the view:

```
<% @widget_ids.each do |id| %>
  <%= render_widget id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have separate options per widgets. You should instantiate different widgets for each configuration, anyway. Do so by passing an id the each widget: http://rdoc.info/github/apotonick/apotomo/Apotomo/WidgetShortcuts:widget

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  has_widgets do |root|
    root << widget(:pictures, 'one', :data => ...)
    root << widget(:pictures, 'two', :data => ...)
  end
  ...
end
```

You can use the widget id in `#render_widget`, then.

```
render_widget 'one'
```

Comment: Ah, interesting approach.  How would I find a list of "loaded" widgets?  I can't use `find_widget(:root)` in neither the controller nor views.  Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: I ended up overriding one of the modules to make apotomo_root available in the views.  Not sure if this is the best route to go. (Added relevant code to the original post).